# windows installer (Wubi) stops

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

When installing with windows installer (Wubi) in XP, installation stops allways when doing "Reticulating splines..." and the laptop freezes

Comment: Just curious which Ubuntu version are you trying to install?

Comment: I think w installer only can install version 12

Comment: Correct it's not suggested for anything above 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking whether the MD5 of the ISO matches up with the one on the website. If that's not the case, re download and recheck. If however they do match up I recommend just burning the ISO to a DVD or use a program such as [LiLi USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to mount the ISO to a USB flash drive. And boot from it, WuBi is not prefect so there is a chance that you are not able to use WuBi on your machine. Hope this helps.